# Docker is "too verbose" in npm-cli-adduser

Tags: docker, npm, npm-cli

When my Dockerfile does the RUN command:

`RUN npm-cli-adduser -r https://$PRIVATE_REPOSITORY_URL/repository/npm-read -u $PRIVATE_USERNAME -p "$PRIVATE_PASSWORD" -e service-foobar@example.com`

It echos the private environment variables in the terminal. I would like to hide these variables, so that users who read the terminal do not see it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker secrets, but you will need to store the variable in a file as far as i understand

Like this:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret,dst=/foobar echo $(cat /foobar) >> test.txt
# In your case 
# RUN npm-cli-adduser -r https://$PRIVATE_REPOSITORY_URL/repository/npm-read -u $PRIVATE_USERNAME -p $(cat /foobar) -e service-foobar@example.com
```

**Build command**

```
docker build --secret id=mysecret,src=mysecret.txt . -t docker-debug
```

**mysecret.txt contect:**

```
YOURPASSWORD
```

[Reference](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information)